# How to test for differences among 3 treatments pre & post, all within subjects?

Tags: anova, spss, repeated-measures

I want to compare the changes in blood pressure occurring following 2 anesthetic drugs. So in a crossover design, each participant comes for 3 sessions and gets either of placebo, drug A or drug B on 3 separate days. The data collected is 'pre drug BP' on each of 3 sessions and 'post drug BP' for each participant.

How should I statistically compare them (I will be using SPSS).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please add to your original question by clicking the gray "edit" at its bottom left. Please add more detail about your setup & data. Your setup / comment doesn't make sense to me. Did you give three drug treatments in a row?

Comment: Are you using diastolic BP, systolic BP, both, or mean BP (defined as [2*diastolic + systolic]/3)?

Comment: Hi, SBP and DBP , both

Answer (score 0):

If truly within subjects, so a participant gets drug A on day 1 and placebo on day 2 and (etc..)  (so NOT pp1: day1 drugA day2 drugA day3 drugA vs pp2: day1 drugB day2 drugB day3 drugB etc)
Then you can use **One Way repeated Measure ANOVA** (if KS's p < .05 then Friedman's ANOVA)